# MessageBox with text color and link

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

How I can make message box as like this in picture:
in C# WPF

http://www7.0zz0.com/2013/08/27/10/853934885.png

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Its simply a url link type control, which is blue like that by default.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the icon with `MessageBoxIcon.Information`. If you want to create a link, you should probably create a different form and send data between your form1 and form2.